# Как вставить переменную в заголовок POST запроса?

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, post, requests

Вот рабочий код. Код используеться для получения информации о группе, а именно название группы:

```
url = f"https://api.green-api.com/waInstance{idInstance}/getGroupData/{apiTokenInstance}"

payload = "{\r\n\t\"groupId\": \"71113181111-1621411111@g.us\"\r\n}"
print(payload)
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
groupInfoChat = json.loads(response.text)

print(groupInfoChat['subject'])
```

Но я хочу заменить и сделать так:

```
groupNumber = '71113181111-1621411111@g.us'

payload = "{\r\n\t\"groupId\": \"groupNumber\"\r\n}"
```

То есть, вместо прямой подстановки номера чата, сделать подстановку перменной. Пробовал разные способы, и конкатенация, и через f'', но не получается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделайте `payload` словарем:

```
payload = {'groupId': '71113181111-1621411111@g.us'}
```

или

```
group_number = '71113181111-1621411111@g.us'
payload = {'groupId': group_number}
```

должно работать...

---

а response перепишите так:

```
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=payload)
```

Comment: Так не работает. Выдает ошибку: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: @ГильмияровРинат `response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=payload)` и `groupInfoChat = response.content`

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. А не могли бы объяснить, в чем ошибка. Имею в виду не код, а именно по смыслу, если не тяжело конечно)

Comment: вы в headers объявили json, так передавайте и получайте в json... почему в документации к api, которую вы привели, payload в виде строки - я без понятия... читайте [правильные доки](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/)! ;)